# Redirect based on symlink using htaccess

Tags: git, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano to deploy Git repos and currently, I'm having an issue with redirection using .htaccess and the symlink setup.

Here's the run-down:

- I have dev.example.com as a sub-domain on MediaTemple GS.
- Under the dev.example.com folder, I have client folders e.g. dev.example.com/client
- Under dev.example.com/client Capistrano has /releases, /shared, /tmp and a symlink of /current pointing to the /releases folder (so any visits to /current always show the curren version of the site)

Ideally, I would like anyone visiting dev.example.com/client to be redirected to that /current folder in order for it to continue following the symlink path.

I put the following in an .htaccess in the /client folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^client.*$ /current [L]
```

But, it fails miserably :(

Normally, there would be an /html folder and it's as simple as using a symlink of: ln -s ./current ./html but given this is a sub-directory the /html has no meaning. (I guess I could create an /html directory and figure out how to make visits to /client go to /html but that seems crazy).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've put the rules in the `/client` folder, then you don't need to match against `client` as it's automatically stripped off. Try just:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /current/ [L]
```

Or if you want requests for `/client/whatever` to also go to `/current/whatever`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /current/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, Jon. Thank you for responding. I ended up using current without the slashes as it's a symlink (for those with Capistrano who read this later on), it looks like, so it's redirecting. Is there a clean way to have it dev.example.com/client/ instead of the dev.example.com/client/current/ it shows as the URL? That's the final piece to this puzzle! Thank you.